# Javascript only draws last of multiple drawings

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing

Okay so i'm embarrassingly unknowledgeable of javascript. I know my ruby and rails pretty solid but have never used js as extensively as i am in my current project.

i have a map that's been drawn on a canvas. on that map, i want drawn multiple position markers (via the provided function). i've given it a list (via rails) of locations to mark. for some reason, it's only drawing the last coordinate.

the javascript is improvised from another source, not mine. this is just the problematic portion:

```
        function plotPosition(long,lat) {
            // Grab a handle to the canvas
            var canvas = document.getElementById('map'),
                ctx;

            // Canvas supported?
            if (canvas.getContext) {
                // Grab the context
                ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                ctx.beginPath();

                // Draw a arc that represent the geo-location of the request
                ctx.arc(
                    degreesOfLongitudeToScreenX(long),
                    degreesOfLatitudeToScreenY(lat),
                    5,
                    0,
                    2 * Math.PI,
                    false
                );

                // Point style
                ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
                ctx.fill();

                ctx.stroke();
            }
        }

        function draw() {
            // Main entry point got the map canvas example

            var canvas = document.getElementById('map'),
                ctx;

            // Canvas supported?
            if (canvas.getContext) {
                ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                // Draw the background
                drawBackground(ctx);

                // Draw the map background
                drawMapBackground(ctx);

                // Draw the map background
                // drawGraticule(ctx);

                // Draw the land
                drawLandMass(ctx);

                <% @events.each do |e| %>
                plotPosition('<%= e.longitude %>','<%= e.latitude %>');
                <% end %>

            } else {
                alert("Canvas not supported!");
            }
        }
```

so my thinking is that the plotPosition function *is* drawing each coordinate, but every time it's given a new coordinate, the old one is erased/moved and replaced with the new one. probably a simple fix here, but i've been at this for hours and to no avail. banging my head.

any ideas as to the problem?

Comment: from your code it could be the server side part which is faulty. Could you console.log (long, lat) inside plotPosition so that you're sure it's being called with right values ?

Comment: Just thoughts, not a solution: put ctx.closePath after ctx.arc to draw a closed circle instead of an open 360 degree arc.  `long` is a future-reserved word in javascript so you might want to use a different variable name.   As @GameAlchemist says, your error is outside the code you've given us visibility of.  You might check the results of degreesOfLongitudeToScreenX(long) and degreesOfLatitudeToScreenY(lat) to be sure they are on-screen coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code example it seems as you are clearing the background too - you're not showing the calls to these methods but I will assume you do this before drawing the new point(s) (?) somewhere else in the code.

If so -

You need to redraw *all* the points you have drawn before you clear the canvas.

One way to do this is to store the points you already have in an array and then call a redraw function to draw everything in there. Or store the points from server directly to the array with converted values and when all points has been converted redraw everything.

Simplified example based on latter approach (which will require some re-factoring):

```
/// GLOBALS (put ctx here instead as well..)

var points = [],
    canvas = document.getElementById('map'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext ? canvas.getContext('2d') : null;

if (ctx === null) {...sorry...};

...

/// somewhere comes the logic to get the points themselves.
...
<% @events.each do |e| %>
storePosition('<%= e.longitude %>','<%= e.latitude %>');
<% end %>
...

/// after new points are added, render them all
renderAll();

function storePosition(long, lat) {

    points.push{
        x: degreesOfLongitudeToScreenX(long)
        y: degreesOfLatitudeToScreenY(lat),
        long: long,
        lat: lat
    }
}

function renderAll();

    /// clear and redraw background of canvas

    drawBackground(ctx);

    // Draw the map background
    drawMapBackground(ctx);

    // Draw the map background
    // drawGraticule(ctx);

    // Draw the land
    drawLandMass(ctx);

    /// now plot all the stored points

    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';

    for(var i = 0, point; point = points[i]; i++) {

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(
            point.x,
            point.y,
            5,
            0,
            2 * Math.PI
        );
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
    }
}
```

You *can* implement a check of x and y to see that they are inside canvas but this is strictly not necessary as canvas will clip them for you and the internal clipping do faster checking than JavaScript will. But for debugging purposes you could always do a check if you suspect this. But you write that the point is plotted but erased when a new point is drawn so I don't think this is the problem here.